# Why is editText section in my Android Studio program not showing up in my AVD?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

This is the XML of one of my `editTexts` but it isn't appearing in my AVD for some reason I am not able to figure out.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextKm"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="28dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="68dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@android:string/unknownName"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    tools:targetApi="o"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonConvMilestoKm"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextMiles" />
```

[image]

Comment: post complete XML code here

Comment: instead of setting height as 0dp change it to `wrap_content`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there was a bug when I created the editTexts before the other components. Later I removed them and created them again right before adding constraints and it started working.